# Wrong filename by image

Tags: php

I have in my directory six images. He shows 2 images and 1 filename. The filename is wrong but he is in the directory but he shows not that image. Can you help me? I want that he show 2 images + 2 correct filename's.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "images1/";
//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
shuffle($images);
?>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" > 
<head>
<title>Image</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)                                              
echo"<img src=\"$images[$i]\"width=\"300\"height=\"400\">"; 
echo basename($images[$i], ".jpg");                                          
?>  
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the output too?

Comment: Enclose your `for` in brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` statement is not correct, use brackets:

```
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
        echo "<img src=\"$images[$i]\" width=\"300\" height=\"400\" />"; 
        echo basename($images[$i], ".jpg");   
    }              
?>
```